# Interator<elementType> it =myCollection.Interator(); Just started programming and want to know what this means?

Tags: java, arrays

```
Interator<elementType> it =myCollection.Interator();
```

Just started programming and want to know what this means?

Comment: It means nothing, unless you mean `Iterator` and `iterator()`. Have you also read the javadoc: it usually describes this in detail.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to use copy & paste than to type something manually...

Answer (score 0):

With iterator you can iterate over your collection! for example you can get next or previous item.
[How to use Iterator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is an object that enables a programmer to traverse lists. it works normally same as for loop for getting elements from array.

reference from [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)

Answer (score 0):

An `Iterator` is the JAVA's implementation of Iterator Pattern of The Design Patterns. It is a utility that gets the individual item in the collection sequentially, checks whether  the collection contains more elements and most importantly removes an item from the collection.

Without the JAVA's collection package, it would be very difficult for individuals to implement collection of items as a detailed study of data structures would be required. Java in the collection package implements all that is required to create different kinds of collections thus saving common users from the details of the data structure implementations.

So this `Iterator` object is basically an utility that saves the users from many common difficulty. I would illustrate it using the following example.

create an `ArrayList` object:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("abc");
.
.
.
.
strings.add("abc");
.
.
.
.
```

now suppose you were to remove the elements whose value is `"abc"`

```
Iterator<String> i = strings.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
   if(i.next().equals("abc")){
      i.remove();
   }
}
```

without the use of iterator it would be with lots of logical thinking and prone to many errors:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
   if(strings.get(i).equals ("abc"){
      strings.remove(i);
   }
}
```